# Lp optimality proof

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

i have a general question.

if there is a general LP problem  $c^Tx$ s.t $A\cdot x \le b$, and $x \ge 0$ and assuming that the components of $c$ are non-zero entries then how can I prove that when $x$ satisfies $a\cdot x < b$ (notice the strict inequality here) and $x > 0$, then $x$ cannot be an optimal solution?